# ExecutreNonQuery and Update Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

Receiving this error when I try saving.

> Incorrect Syntax near the word update.

Seems like an obvious fix but I can't seem to find it. Hoping fresh eyes will help! Thanks

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button EditButton = (Button)EditLoginView.FindControl("EditButton");
    Button SaveButton = (Button)EditLoginView.FindControl("SaveButton");

        TitleLanguage.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        LanguageView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        EditButton.Visible = true;
        SaveButton.Visible = false;

        //update the file in the database
        string strQuery = "UPDATE pages SET en_content = @en_Content, fr_Content = @fr_content, fr_Title=@fr_title, en_Title=@en_title, update=@update WHERE link_title = @link_title";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@en_title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Edit_EnglishT.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fr_title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Edit_FrenchT.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@en_content", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Edit_English.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fr_content", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Edit_French.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@update", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@link_", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = linktitle;
        UpdateData(cmd);



}


 private Boolean UpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["randolphConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UPDATE` is a *[reserved keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)* in T-SQL. You should use it with square brackets like `[UPDATE]`

Like;

```
string strQuery = @"UPDATE pages SET en_content = @en_Content, fr_Content = @fr_content, fr_Title=@fr_title, en_Title=@en_title,
                  [update]=@update WHERE link_title = @link_title";
                  ^^^^^^^^
```

As a general recomendation, don't use reserved keywords for your identifiers and object names in your database.

Also change your

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@link_", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = linktitle;
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@link_title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = linktitle;
```

Because you declared your parameter name as `@link_title` not `@link_` in your `strQuery`.

**EDIT**: For clarification, you don't need to use a method (`UpdateData`) for that such a process. Just use like this;

```
String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["randolphConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
     string strQuery = @"UPDATE pages SET en_content = @en_Content, fr_Content = @fr_content, fr_Title=@fr_title, en_Title=@en_title, [update]=@update WHERE link_title = @link_title";
     cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
     cmd.Parameters...;
     .....
     .....
     cmd.Connection.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: what a dummy mistake... it fixed all my error messages... but now it is not updating my database? is my updatedata function an appropriate way to update the database?

Comment: still no dice and no errors... It seems to run but just doesn't update.

Comment: @trowse You sure your connection string is right? Did you debug your code? What is your `cmd` looks like just before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line?

Comment: yes, I use the same connection string to bring the data in from the database for editing.

Answer (score 2):

You define the field `update` which is a reserved keyword.

Try `[update]` instead like in this sample:

```
UPDATE pages
SET    en_content = @en_Content
,      fr_Content = @fr_content
,      fr_Title=@fr_title
,      en_Title=@en_title
,      [update]=@update
WHERE  link_title = @link_title
```

Comment: what a dummy mistake... it fixed all my error messages... but now it is not updating my database? is my updatedata function an appropriate way to update the database?

Comment: @trowse: your method is not the problem. Maybe trailing or leading spaces? Does the update work directly on the database?

Comment: It is supposed to be updating the database directly but doesn't want too.

Comment: @trowse: I mean using database tools like SSMS.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to go about doing that? Can I do it in visual studio?

Comment: @trowse: yes. Go to your database in the Server Explorer and execute the query there.

Comment: @trowse: well, it should not actually, so there is something wrong. I suggest to create a new question and include sample data, etc.

Comment: @trowse: I would be glad to help you but I need serious more info. If you create a new question I will take a look.

Comment: Just posted patrick... I've discovered the problem (I think) but i'm unsure how to fix it... my form data is not being received by the code... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133517/not-getting-variables-from-page-to-submit-to-database

Comment: @trowse: okay. I will take a look. Can you close this question by accepting one of the answers provided?

Answer (score 2):

In your last parameter, you use @link_title
but in the Parameter.Add, you use:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@link_", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = linktitle;
```

Try to change for this one:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@link_title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = linktitle;
```

Comment: what a dummy mistake... it fixed all my error messages... but now it is not updating my database? is my updatedata function an appropriate way to update the database?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you! Check the UPDATE query of the first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246182/sql-update-statement-in-c-sharp