# Not getting variables from page... to submit to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am unable to get the values that the page posts to submit to my page.

The form probably is a bit confusing but basically on page load it shows the content... if a user in logged in it shows an edit button they are able to click which changes the view to my form where they can edit the page.

Then they click the save button which in turn submits the data to the database.

Here is the form I'm submitting.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="Title" Runat="Server">
  <asp:MultiView ID="TitleLanguage" runat="server">
                <asp:View ID="EnglishT" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="en_title" runat="server"/></asp:View>
                 <asp:View ID="FrenchT" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="fr_title" runat="server"/></asp:View>
       <asp:View ID="EditT" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Edit_EnglishT" runat="server" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Edit_FrenchT" runat="server" />
       </asp:View>
      </asp:MultiView>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ID="EditLoginView"><LoggedInTemplate><div id="logged">
        <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" Text="Edit Page" CssClass="loggedbutton" PostBackUrl="~/page.aspx"/>
        <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" visible="false" Text="Save" CssClass="loggedbutton" PostBackUrl="~/page.aspx" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
    </div>
</LoggedInTemplate></asp:LoginView>
   <asp:MultiView ID="LanguageView" runat="server">
                <asp:View ID="English" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="en_content" runat="server"/></asp:View>
                 <asp:View ID="French" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="fr_content" runat="server"/></asp:View>
       <asp:View ID="Edit" runat="server">
<h1>English Page</h1>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="Edit_English" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="400px" />
<h1>French Page</h1>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="Edit_French" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="400px" />
       </asp:View>
   </asp:MultiView>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the code I'm using to get the variables.

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button EditButton = (Button)EditLoginView.FindControl("EditButton");
    Button SaveButton = (Button)EditLoginView.FindControl("SaveButton");



        //update the file in the database
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["randolphConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{ 
        string strQuery = " UPDATE pages  SET en_content = @en_Content, fr_Content = @fr_content, fr_Title=@fr_title, en_Title=@en_title, last_update=@last_update WHERE link_title = @link";
            cmd.CommandText= strQuery;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@en_title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Edit_EnglishT.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fr_title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Edit_FrenchT.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@en_content", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Edit_English.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fr_content", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Edit_French.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@last_update", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@link", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = linktitle;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        TitleLanguage.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        LanguageView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        EditButton.Visible = true;
        SaveButton.Visible = false;
        loadpage();

}
```

I'm new to asp.net so I'm trying to use what I know about asp classic to pull... basically what i'm missing is the request.form section... Any help would be great!

Comment: What is an error that you are getting?

Comment: No error. The btnSave_Click is not receiving any of the variables. When I replace Edit_EnglishT.Text and all the other values in the Parameters section with a static string "testing" the database updates.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! When I was calling upon the linktitle variable it didn't exist because even though I declared it as a public variable when the page was refreshing it erased the variable.

Worked around that by placing the information in a hidden field... I'm sure there is another way to do this but I couldn't figure out how.