# What is wrong with this query? I'm providing values for all of the parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, parameters

I have a vb.net project with an update function in, where I am passing values into a database SQL function from the save button click method.

In the database table that I am updating, there are 10 fields. As you can see in the query below, I am providing 10 values, one for each field.

Yet, still, when it hits the line `Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()`, it outputs the error

> No value given for one or more required parameters

I can't work out why - Can anybody else?

```vb
Public Shared Function UpdateFreight(ByVal OrderNumber As Integer, _
                                     ByVal OrderRef As String, _
                                     ByVal FreightNum As Integer, _
                                     ByVal FreightVal As Double, _
                                     ByVal FreightDesc As String, _
                                     ByVal ProductCode As String, _
                                     ByVal EstDelivery As DateTime, _
                                     ByVal SCode As String, _
                                     ByVal CCode As String, _
                                     ByVal AddressCode As String, _  
                                     con As OleDbConnection)

    Try
        Dim Dc As New OleDbCommand
        Dc.Connection = con

        Dc = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Order_Freight] SET [Order_Number] = ?, _
                                            [Order_Reference] = ?, _
                                            [Freight_Number] = ?, [Freight_Val] = ?, _
                                            [Freight_Desc] = ?, [Product_Code] = ?,_
                                            [Est_Delivery] = ?, [Supplier_Code] = ?, _
                                            [Customer_Code] = ?, [Address_Code] = ? _
                                            WHERE [OrderNumber] = ?", con)

        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ono", OrderNumber)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oref", OrderRef)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fnum", FreightNum)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fval", FreightVal)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdesc", FreightDesc)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", ProductCode)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estd", EstDelivery)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scode", SCode)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccode", CCode)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acode", AddressCode)
        Dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@onum", OrderNumber)

        Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog(ex)
        MsgBox("Failed to update data, refer to error log")
        Throw

    End Try
End Function
```

If it helps, this is where the function is called

```vb
    database.UpdateFreight(OrderNumber, OrderRef, FNum, FreightVal, FreightDesc, PCode, EstDate, SCode, custCode, Address, con)
```

And to clarify that all parameters are being given values

[image]

(Also, it isn't to do with code formatting, I've adapted the formatting a ton just for the readability of the question, it doesn't look like this in vb)

Comment: while you are debugging can you open `Dc.Parameters` before you call ExecuteNonQuery to see what value all the parameters have? Any missing there? Any out of order?

Comment: Does your sql statement not need to have named parameters? "set [Order_Number] = :ono" (or whatever the correct access syntax is) ? Having had a look at our codebase, it looks like you add them to the parameter collectionwithout the @ and then specify them in the sql with a colon.

Comment: Is that exactly how your code is - i.e. are you sure you didn't change more than just the formatting?  I only ask since you are initializing `Dc` twice, which seems a little odd.  Your SQL string is also a little strange in the question - it has `_` continuation characters, but each line is not terminated and there is no concatenation `&`.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer According to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), "The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text."

Comment: `SET [Order_Number] ... WHERE [OrderNumber]`  I dont_see the_second column in_the table_image.  For a single table, a configured DataAdapter would handle all that for you - no need for a "helper" class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update statement in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246182/sql-update-statement-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Brad nope, they're all there, that's why I find it quite strange

Comment: @AndrewMortimer I've been doing it using the same syntax elsewhere in the program, so I wouldn't think that was the problem. I may try it this way though

Comment: @Mark Yeah, the `_` characters are just there in the question to stop it being all one long line, but in the actual program it's just all on a single line.

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah I didn't think I needed the first `[Order_Number]` in, I didn't have it originally, but it gave me the same error, which is why I added it, thinking it was the missing value

Comment: Can you try the update with just one field updated and see if that works? If so, keep adding until it breaks. Otherwise I suppose there is something fundamentally wrong with the update.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer For some reason, starting with one worked, then adding the rest one at a time and testing at each stage is fixing it, despite the code being a direct replica.... Strange one, guess we'll never know what went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is because you have a column misnamed

```
UPDATE [Order_Freight] SET [Order_Number] = ?, 
[Order_Reference] = ?, 
[Freight_Number] = ?, [Freight_Val] = ?, 
[Freight_Desc] = ?, [Product_Code] = ?,
[Est_Delivery] = ?, [Supplier_Code] = ?, 
[Customer_Code] = ?, [Address_Code] = ? 
WHERE [OrderNumber] = ?
```

Notice `SET [Order_Number] = ?` and `WHERE [OrderNumber] = ?`. One of those is probably not right and is being interpreted as an unknown column and thus Access treats it as a parameter. Fix the spelling on your Order Number column to be right.

Comment: You should be awarded the "Eagle eye" badge. :)

Comment: @Andre hehe came back at it fresh today :)

Comment: Of course, how obvious! I can't believe I didn't realise, and nor did anyone else on here for that matter... Thank you haha

Answer (score 1):

Since `OleDb` doesn't support named parameters, and looking at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) doc for `OleDbCommand.Parameters`, might it work if you pass in your parameters as `OleDbParameter` objects instead? For example -

```
 Dc = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Order_Freight] SET [Order_Number] = ?, _
                                        [Order_Reference] = ?, _
                                        [Freight_Number] = ?, [Freight_Val] = ?, _
                                        [Freight_Desc] = ?, [Product_Code] = ?,_
                                        [Est_Delivery] = ?, [Supplier_Code] = ?, _
                                        [Customer_Code] = ?, [Address_Code] = ? _
                                        WHERE [OrderNumber] = ?", con)

        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ono", OrderNumber))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@oref", OrderRef))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@fnum", FreightNum))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@fval", FreightVal))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@fdesc", FreightDesc))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@pcode", ProductCode))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@estd", EstDelivery))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@scode", SCode))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ccode", CCode))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@acode", AddressCode))
        Dc.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@onum", OrderNumber))

        Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, this still gives me the same problem, however