# Unhandled Format Exception with string

Tags: c#, string

The code below is for updating the value in a database,

```
          string updateCom = ("UPDATE Login SET Username = '" + textUsername.Text + "', Password = '" + textPassword.Text + "', Role = '" + comboBox1.Text + "', First_Name = '" + char.Parse(textFirstName.Text) + "', Last_Name = '" + char.Parse(textLastName.Text) + "', Age = " + int.Parse(textAge.Text) + "', Gender = " + char.Parse(textAge.Text) + " WHERE User_ID = " + textUser_ID.Text);
```

the whole thing is enclosed in a try catch method and upon debugging i got

> "FormatException was Unhandled"

, it also says that string must be exactly one character long. This unhandled exception only happens when i input "John Harambe" as the first name. Can anyone enlighten me on the correct format?

MY SOLUTION TO MY QUESTION:

so i used Parameterized Query as suggested by one of the commenters, here is my code so far;

```
       updateCom = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Login"
            + "SET Username = @username,"
            + "Password = @password,"
            + "Role = @role,"
            + "First_Name = @firstName,"
            + "Last_Name = @lastName,"
            + "Age = @age,"
            + "Gender = @gender"
            + "WHERE User_ID = @user_ID");

        updateCom.Connection = searchCon;
        searchCon.Open();

        String Username = textUsername.Text;
        String Password = textPassword.Text;
        String Role = comboBox1.Text;
        String First_Name = textFirstName.Text;
        String Last_Name = textLastName.Text;
        String Age = textAge.Text;
        String Gender = textGender.Text;

        if (searchCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            updateCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
            updateCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password);
            updateCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", Role);
            updateCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", First_Name);
            updateCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", Last_Name);
            updateCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", Age);
            updateCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", Gender);

            try
            {
                updateCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (MessageBox.Show("Data UPDATED.", "Admin Power",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    searchCon.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(MessageBox.Show("Data NOT UPDATED", "Admin Power",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                searchCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

and it still throws and unhandled exception

> "Error syntax near 'Username'."

Comment: See `char.Parse(....Text)`.

Comment: When debugging, you should also see exactly which method is throwing the exception. That method does something you do not want. Read its documentation for details.

Comment: Please use Parameterized Query
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246182/sql-update-statement-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errr, `char.parse` requires a one-character string.

[char.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

So, of course, if your first name or surname string is longer, you're going to get that exception...