# How to insert same value in two table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

I have Employee and CT Employee SQL tables with Same Attributes
I want to if I add a value in CT EMPLOYEE table this value will add EMPLOYEE table
how can I do that?

```
class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
                    connect.ConnectionString = "Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = DigitalizationDeneme; Integrated Security = true";
                    SqlCommand con = new SqlCommand("UPDATE", connect);
                    connect.Open();
                Console.WriteLine($"Connection State : {connect.State}");
                var saveNumber = con.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(saveNumber);

                Console.ReadLine();
     }
        }
    }
    Employee.cs  

        class Employee
        {
            public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Gid { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }


            public string CostCenter { get; set; }

            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime LeaveDate { get; set; }
            public string ContractType { get; set; }
            public double WeeklyWorkingHour { get; set; }
            public int MenagerID { get; set; }
            public string scdDept { get; set; }
            public string SapCompanyCode { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastUpdatedTime { get; set; }


        }
    }

    ctemployee cs
        class ctEmployee
        {
            public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Gid { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }


            public string CostCenter { get; set; }

            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime LeaveDate { get; set; }
            public string ContractType { get; set; }
            public double WeeklyWorkingHour { get; set; }
            public int MenagerID { get; set; }
            public string scdDept { get; set; }
            public string SapCompanyCode { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastUpdatedTime { get; set; }


        }
    }
```

I expect if I add value CTEMPLOYEE in database same value sees in Employee table
Please help me I need quickly help.

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking how to write a SQL `INSERT` statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update statement in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246182/sql-update-statement-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Also: [C# – Read, Insert, Update, Delete From SQL Database](http://lamahashim.blogspot.com/2010/04/c-read-insert-update-delete-from-sql.html)

Comment: "I have Employee and CT Employee SQL tables with Same Attributes" Which begs the question - Why? What's the difference between these two entities?

Comment: Indeed, only one class is sufficient.

Comment: Check your model and see if the two columns are linked then writing to one will automatically write to the other.